# How to specify column position when adding new column to a csv file using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, columnsorting, import-csv, add-member

How can I specify the column position when adding a new column to an existing csv file?

I want to add the new column as second column (Not at the end what the default is).
The first column is always the same, but the other columns can differ per file (so it is not known on beforehand which columns (names and order) there are (with the exception of the first column, which always contains the name)).

As far as I know there is no position parameter for `Add-Member`.

**Sample code:**

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "attendees.csv" -Delimiter ';' 

foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    $row | Add-Member -'GUID' -Value (New-Guid).Guid -MemberType NoteProperty 
}

$csv | Export-Csv new_attendees.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I would use [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) for this: `Import-Csv -Path "attendees.csv |Select-Object -Property <name column 1>, @{ n='Name'; e={ (New-Guid).Guid } }, <name column n>` | Export-Csv ...

Comment: There are a lot of looping in the answers given, but the best way is to use a number of pipes. That would conserve both memory and probably be much faster than all the looping. Here's the main trick: `$csv | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header $csv_header_old | Select-Object -Property $csv_header_new | ForEach-Object {...} | ConvertTo-Csv ...`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you do not know the column names at forehand.
Using [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object) with a [calculated property](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) for this:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path "attendees.csv" -Delimiter ';' 
$Properties = [Collections.Generic.List[Object]]$csv[0].psobject.properties.name
$Properties.Insert(1, @{ n='Guid'; e={ New-Guid } }) # insert at column #1
$csv |Select-Object -Property $Properties |Export-Csv new_attendees.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

---

**Explanation:** (Updated 2022-11-12)

- Each object PowerShell has een hidden `PSObject` property where you can [dynamically access](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/learn/deep-dives/everything-about-pscustomobject#dynamically-accessing-properties) information about the property as e.g. its name.
- Using the PowerShell [Member-Access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_member-access_enumeration) feature will list all the `psobject.properties.name` as an array of scalar strings.

  - I am using just the first object `$csv[0]` to determine the property (column) names as I do not want to choke the PowerShell pipeline and continue to support [one-at-a-time processing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_pipelines#one-at-a-time-processing). In other words, I presume that the following objects have unified property names. Any well written PowerShell [cmdlet](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/cmdlet-overview) follows the **strongly encouraged development guideline** to [implement for the middle of a pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/strongly-encouraged-development-guidelines#implement-for-the-middle-of-a-pipeline)
- Thanks to the impliciet [.Net conversion](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/lang-spec/chapter-06#618-net-conversion), it is easy to type cast the PowerShell Array (of  property names) to the [`Collections.Generic.List[Object]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1) type
- Which happens to have a [`List<T>.Insert(Int32, T)` Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.insert#system-collections-generic-list-1-insert(system-int32-0)). This lets you insert a item (in this case an `object`) at a certain position (in this case: `1`)

  - Note that this method is *The zero-based*
- The [`-Property`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/select-object#-property) parameter of the `Select-Object` cmdlet, doesn't just support an ordered list of property names but also [calculated properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_calculated_properties) which is used here to create complete property along with its name, value (expression) in the form of:
  `@{ n='Guid'; e={ New-Guid } }`

Comment: Interesting, but would be more helpful if you could also explain what the `$Properties` line(s) does.

Comment: @not2qubit, I have added an explanation to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add-Member does not let you specify at which position to add a property to an object. So you have to build a new object where you can control the position of the property, e.g.:

```
$newObjects = @(
    foreach ($row in $csv){
        $attrsHt = [ordered]@{
            [propertyName]=[propertyValue]
            Guid=([guid]::NewGuid()).guid
            [propertyName]=[propertyValue]
            [propertyName]=[propertyValue]
        }
        New-Object -TypeName psobject -Property $attrsht
    }
)
```

Or you can use select-object to change the order of the output:

```
foreach ($row in $csv)
{
    $row | Add-Member -Name 'GUID' -Value (New-Guid).Guid -MemberType NoteProperty 
}

$csv | select-object [propertyName],Guid,[propertyName],[propertyName] | export-csv new_attendees.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Ok as the propertyNames are unknown/dynamic you could do:

```
#Get the csv header and split by delimiter to get array of property names
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$csvHeader = (get-content [path])[0] -split ","

#Insert Guid at 2nd Position
$csvHeader.insert(1,'GUID')

$csv | select-object $csvHeader | export-csv new_attendees.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: indeed missed the at... but what is the benefit of the CAST vs. new-object?

Comment: @Toni It is not known on beforehand which columns (names and order) there are.

Comment: ok, I'll updated the code - hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an easy way to insert a property into an object in-place at a specific index, but here's a quick proof-of-concept I knocked out to create a new object based on the original...

It could do with some error handling and perhaps some parameter attributes to support the pipeline, but it basically works...

```
function Insert-NoteProperty
{

    param(
        [pscustomobject] $InputObject,
        [string] $Name,
        [object] $Value,
        [int] $Index
    )

    $properties = @($InputObject.psobject.Properties);

    $result = [ordered] @{};

    # append the properties before the index
    for( $i = 0; $i -lt $Index; $i++ )
    {
        $result.Add($properties[$i].Name, $properties[$i].Value);
    }

    # append the new property
    $result.Add($Name, $Value);

    # append the properties after the index
    for( $i = $Index; $i -lt $properties.Length; $i++ )
    {
        $result.Add($properties[$i].Name, $properties[$i].Value);
    }

    return [pscustomobject] $result;

}
```

Example:

```
$original = [pscustomobject] [ordered] @{ "aaa"="bbb"; "ccc"="ddd" }

$original
# aaa ccc
# --- ---
# bbb ddd

$updated = Insert-NoteProperty `
    -InputObject $original `
    -Name        "new" `
    -Value       "value" `
    -Index       1;

$updated
# aaa new   ccc
# --- ---   ---
# bbb value ddd
```

You can use this with a csv file as follows:

```
$csv = @"
aaa,ccc
bbb,ddd
"@

$data = $csv | ConvertFrom-Csv;

$newdata = $data | foreach-object {
    Insert-NoteProperty `
        -InputObject $_ `
        -Name        "new" `
        -Value       "value" `
        -Index       1
}

$newcsv = $newdata | ConvertTo-Csv

$newcsv
# "aaa","new","ccc"
# "bbb","value","ddd"
```

Comment: @mclaton How can I create a custom object using 'Import-CSV'

Comment: ```Inport-CSV``` returns pscustomobjects for you - e.g. ```("aaa, ccc`r`nbbb, ddd" | convertfrom-csv)[0].gettype().fullname``` gives ```System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject```

Comment: Added an example with ```ConvertFrom-Csv```, but should work the same with ```Import-Csv```. Integrating it with the pipeline would let it be a bit more succinct - left as an exercise for the reader ;-).